# What creates the flow between the two sentences?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I wrote the text. I think there is no need to add linking words like **specifically** or **this is because** before the second sentence but I don't know why. I learned that we can create a sense of flow by using linking words, reference words like they or this, or repeated words or ideas. But none of these rules applies here. Can you explain what creates the flow between the two sentences? How can I explain this to low-level English learners who want to start every single sentence with a linking word?

> A declining population in the countryside can have detrimental effects
> on local businesses. **(Specifically,)** with fewer residents, there
> is reduced demand for goods and services, leading to a downturn in
> local businesses and bringing inconvenience to the daily
> lives of the local community.

Comment: There is no "flow". You are merely further elaborating your first point.

Comment: @Lambie, you don't think the first sentence flows naturally to the second?

Comment: I think it is a point that further illustrates your first point. You can call that "flow" if you like. For me, it is paragraph development.

Comment: When you tell a story, you don't in any language say *Then* to start each sentence. Same here, you just continue your point. Anyway, doesn't "fewer residents" echo "declining population"?

Comment: This might belong better on Writing SE because it's general writing advice about how to structure a paragraph, rather than anything specific to the English language.

Comment: If the second sentence flows naturally from the first on a conceptual level, there's no need for a linking word to create the segue. Indeed, **with fewer residents** is already such a seque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great observation. Originally, using connecting words can be helpful. As we improve our writing, we eventually drop some of these words for more intelligent sentence connections, as you are aware.

> A declining population in the countryside can have detrimental effects
> on local businesses. (Specifically,) with fewer residents, there is
> reduced demand for goods and services, leading to a downturn in local
> businesses and bringing inconvenience to the daily lives of the local
> community.

The best way to explain why connecting words aren't better depends on the specific sentence. In this example, there are two reasons. First, omitting "specifically" makes it read almost like there is an implied colon. The pauses you take are the ~same as if you wrote "businesses: with fewer." Next, and more directly, you could say specifically is redundant: you don't add anything by adding "specifically." The reader knows that the second sentence is more specific! So, we aren't adding anything. Connecting words should only be used when they actually serve a purpose, or if they are there as a particular style. For example, "for example" is used in this sentence to make it obvious that this is merely one out of many possible examples, and "so" is used earlier to portray a conversational style.

Comment: I like this answer. It is respectful and encouraging to the questionner and replies in language that doesn't require advanced grammar knowledge to understand.